# How to check if cell value is greater than X, get the difference from those 2 values and add to the next cell in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an excel problem I really need help with! 
I want to use functions in column Day1 and Day2. 
Goal: To check each cell and make sure it doesn't exceed 27. If it does, get the difference between the cell value and 27, carry over the difference and add to the next cell.

Example, in column Day1, it will check if 13 is greater than 27. It's not so it will leave that value as it is. Same with 14 and 26. The next value in Day1 Column is 29 which is greater than 27, so it will change that cell value to 27 and carry over the difference (29-27)=2 and add to the cell below so 31 + 2 = 33. Now 33 is greater than 27 so it will again change that value to 27 and carry over the difference (33-27) = 6 and add it to first cell in Day2 Column: 6 + 5=11.

The process will be repeated for Day2 column as well. If the last value in Day2 column doesn't exceed 27, then leave as it is. Move to the next column and repeat that process of checking if cell value is greater than 27.

Current:

```
Time    Day1 Day2
Hour0   13   5
Hour1   14   15
Hour2   26   29
Hour3   29   26
Hour4   31   4
```

Desired:

```
Time    Day1 Day2
Hour0   13   11
Hour1   14   15
Hour2   26   27
Hour3   27   27
Hour4   27   5
```

Now I'm not an excel expert so I tried few if statements but don't think that is the way to solve this problem. I did, `if(A1>27, 27, A1)` which is checking if A1 is greater than 27, change that value to 27 else leave that value as it is. But then I also need another if statement, `if(A1>27, A2=(A1-27) + A2, A1)`
Trying to find a way to combine those 2 if statements or are there other excel functions/secrets that I can use?
Please any help is appreciated. 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using VBA, with a "carry forward" variable to keep track of how much is able to be allocated to the next cell:

```
Sub runMe()
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim cf As Double
    With ActiveSheet
        'assumes headings in row 1, and column 1
        lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For c = 2 To lastCol
            For r = 2 To lastRow
                cf = cf + CDbl(.Cells(r, c).Value)
                If cf > 27 Then
                    .Cells(r, c).Value = 27
                    cf = cf - 27
                Else
                    .Cells(r, c).Value = cf
                    cf = 0
                End If
            Next
        Next
        'place any final carry forward into a new column
        If cf > 0 Then
            .Cells(2, lastCol + 1).Value = cf
        Else
            .Cells(2, lastCol + 1).ClearContents
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer is also correct but wanted to be fair so accepted the first answer because that person answered first. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @AnujaK - No worries about where the "tick" goes, but be aware that Darkisa's answer doesn't carry forward from the bottom of the first column to the top of the second column.  (That, and the limitation to two columns, was why I posted an answer after they did.)

Comment: @YowE3k- Yes, you are right, just realized that and that is what I wanted. Thank you. Quick question, what if I wanted to ignore 2 columns instead of just 1?

Comment: @AnujaK - if you mean you have "headings" (or whatever) in columns A and B, and data starts in column C, then change `For c = 2 To lastCol` to `For c = 3 To lastCol`.  (And check whether `lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` is still appropriate - that is finding the last used cell in column 1, so change the 1 to 2 if it is more appropriate to use column B to find the row containing the last used cell.)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use Visual Basic. Insert the following code into your sheet and run it. It will do what you are looking for.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim lngLoopCtr As Long
    Dim value_1 As Long
    Dim value_2 As Long
    lngLastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For lngLoopCtr = 2 To lngLastRow Step 1
        value_1 = Range("B" & lngLoopCtr)
        value_2 = Range("B" & lngLoopCtr + 1)
        If value_1 > 27 Then
            Range("B" & lngLoopCtr + 1) = value_2 + (value_1 - 27)
            Range("B" & lngLoopCtr) = 27
        End If
    Next lngLoopCtr

    For lngLoopCtr = 2 To lngLastRow Step 1
        value_1 = Range("C" & lngLoopCtr).Value
        value_2 = Range("C" & lngLoopCtr + 1).Value
        If value_1 > 27 Then
            Range("C" & lngLoopCtr + 1) = value_2 + (value_1 - 27)
            Range("C" & lngLoopCtr) = 27
        End If
    Next lngLoopCtr
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! While this solves my issue, the code seems a bit hardcoded meaning if I wanted to add more columns, it doesn't work.